# AngularJS ui router - How can I ignore certain routes?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using `ui-router` in my web application. On one of my views I have a canvas which I am drawing to using a 3rd party library. This library attempts to dynamically load images (HTTP GET). My problem is `ui.router`'s `$urlRouterProvider` is handling the routing and therefore all image requests are resulting in a 404 error.

How is this typically handled in an AngularJS application? Is there a way to ignore specific routes?

My route configuration looks like this:

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
//
// For any unmatched url, redirect to /state1
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
//
// Now set up the states
$stateProvider
    .state('main', {
        url: "/",
        templateUrl: "partials/main.html"
    })
    .state('login', {
        url: "/login",
        controller: 'LoginCtrl',
        templateUrl: "partials/login.html"
    })
    .state('signup', {
        url: '/signup',
        controller: 'SignupCtrl',
        templateUrl: 'partials/signup.html'
    })
  });
```

I'd like to ignore any routes matching `'/assets/*'` and allow those requests to pass right through to the server.

Comment: Are you sure `$urlRouterProvider` is handling requests sent by your third party library? Surely the library does not alter the `$location`, which "parses the URL in the browser address bar". I think the short answer to your question is: no, but why would you want to, it would drop your single page app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is typically dealt with at the server level (Express here):

```
app.use express.static(path.join(__dirname, "assets"))
```

So that any url with "/js/app.js" will be rendered as an asset. It shouldn't be something angular has to deal with. I've got a very similar $stateProvider that I grabbed off of some boilerplate and there's no special case for assets in the $stateProvider.

Do you have script or img tags inside of a controller or view boundary? That could explain what you are seeing.

Comment: Oh geez.. you're probably right. I'll make sure the image is in a public area.

Comment: yeah.. I'm a dingle. Thanx

Comment: Sweet, that was easy.